# Inverting Op Amp Output Voltage

Tags: operational-amplifier

Why is the output of an inverting op amp limited by its supply voltage? I've always been wondering why is this so. I never found an exact reason for it. Also, if I have a +12 and -12 supply, why is the output below 24Vpp and not exactly 24Vpp?

Answer (score 4):

Inside each op-amp are two little transistor men as illustrated in Win Hill's Art of Electronics:

[image]

In this case say C is connected to V+ and E is connected to the output. There's another one (not shown) standing on his head say with C connected to V- and E connected to the output.

All that transistor man can do is adjust that variable resistor according to Ib (which comes from the input stages of the amplifier). The best he can do is turn the pot all the way down so that the output is connected to the supply (and in fact he can't quite get there).

So all the op-amp can do is pull its output somewhere between the two supply lines, there is no internal voltage source to allow it to exceed the supplies. Most op-amps if not too heavily loaded can pull the output to within a volt or two of the supply rails, some much closer, especially if lightly loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Barring an output transformer, the output of any amplifier is limited to the supply voltage since there is no way for the active devices in the amplifier to operate beyond that voltage.  In fact, because of voltage drops in the internal circuitry of the amplifier (due to current flow in the output stage resistors and transistors to keep the amplifier in its linear operating region), the maximum output voltage will always be less than the supply voltage.  Even if the amplifier is overdriven so that the output transistors are in saturation, there will always be some voltage drop across them, limiting the output voltage to less than the supply voltage. Any good book on solid state circuits will explain all of the details.

Answer (score 0):

Voltage is a potential for charge, as height is a potential for mass, or pressure is a potential for fluids.

If you have an elevator lifting bowling balls from 0 meters to 100 meters, how can you get a ball higher than 100 meters?

If your garden hose supply is 30 psi, how can you have a pressure greater than 30 psi?

Of course these analogies don't go very far, but it's a start to thinking about the problem intuitively.

Answer (score -1):

*Think* about it.  How is a circuit supposed to drive to a voltage outside its supply voltage range?

The final drive stage uses transistors to variably connect the output to some linear combination of the supply rails.  This is not exactly how it works, but think of a potentiometer connected between the supply rails.  You can get any voltage from one supply rail to the other, but not outside the supply range.

Mathematically, the output voltage can be (A x V+) + ((1-A) x V-), with A being restricted to the 0-1 range.

There is no means to make a voltage outside the supply voltage range.  Let's say you have a circuit that is given 0 to 5 V power.  How is it supposed to produce 6 V out without having 6 V somewhere to drive the output to?  It is possible to make a higher voltage from a lower one, which is what a boost converter does.  However, that's a whole separate problem from a opamp, and not suitable for integrating onto the same chip for a variety of reasons.  You could make some kind of module that produces ±10 V out from only a 6 V battery, but that requires a lot more than a "opamp".